# PowerShell Active Directory AddAccessRule

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to add a Computer Object to the security of another Computer object in AD and give it Full Control.

```
$ou = [ADSI]"LDAP://CN=Tester1,OU=test,OU=Test1,DC=contoso,DC=com"

$sec = $ou.psbase.ObjectSecurity

$act = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$adrights = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::GenericAll

$who = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.???? -ArgumentList "domain\ComputerObject"
$newrule1 = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule -ArgumentList $who, $adrights, $act

$sec.AddAccessRule($newrule1)

$ou.psbase.CommitChanges()
```

With the line (New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.??) what is the correct class for Computer object? (I have tried .NTaccount)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was

```
$who = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTaccount -ArgumentList "domain\ComputerObject$"
```

the $ specifies a computer Object.

Comment: No, `ComputerObject$` is the actual samaccountname of the computer account